# MySQL MariaDB inserting wrong time in column of data type datetime

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE tblWidget (
    id int,
    title varchar(255),
    name varchar(255),
    dateAdded datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW());
```

and this is my insert query:

```
INSERT INTO tblWidget (id, title, name)
    VALUES (602, 'title', 'name');
```

and the values after executing the `select` statement are:

```
id   title   name   dateAdded
607  title   name   2016-03-10 23:04:20
```

Everything is ok except time. At the time of insertion the time of my computer was 3:15 and inserted time was different.

Comment: You might be interested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-time-zone-of-mysql

Comment: Which version are you running?  What timezones are in effect on the two machines?

Answer (score 2):

NOW() gets datetime from machine where MySQL server runs.